# Is this connection through JFK airport doable?

Tags: transit, jfk, delta-air-lines, yyz, edi

I'm currently deciding whether to book this flight, the only doubt I have is the return flight.

- Delta DL6304 - Toronto (YYZ) to JFK @ 8:24PM
- 51 minutes wait
- Delta DL409 - JFK @ 9:15PM to Edinburgh (EDI)

So I figured domestic flights for Delta operate at T2 at JFK and international flights at T4, so I wouldn't have to change terminals.

Does this sound achievable or risky? I'd guess the JFK to EDI flight would be the last one of the day?

The only time I missed a flight (by over an hour) was at Frankfurt with Lufthansa where I was re-booked on the next flight....

Comment: Since this is a single ticket, you don't have much to worry about. Is it a change of plane? If not then it's not a concern. Even if it is I believe Delta has built a lot of slack into arrivals and departure that the time is really something closer to 1 hr 30 minutes and they will ferry you to your gate expeditiously.

Comment: Delta has only one daily JFK-EDI nonstop. If you're rebooked, it will be on flights with another connection. I'd take an earlier flight out of YYZ though. The one you're contemplating is often late and occasionally cancelled.

Comment: @MichaelHampton How do you know if it's "often late"? I'd generally allow more time for connections when possible, but currently not seeing any other option.

Comment: Be aware that a flight from Toronto may use the domestic terminal since you will have pre-cleared US immigration. Google does list DL6304 as arriving at 8:02 on the one date I checked, though.

Comment: Thanks for the input all - I might have to consider getting a return flight EDI-JFK, then figure my from NYC-Montreal then YYZ-JFK...

Comment: Note that DL6304 is not currently operating between YYZ and JFK.  (The YYZ–JFK flight will be reassigned this number after March 8.)

Comment: Looks like @MichaelSeifert covered that in his answer.

Answer (score 5):

[According to Delta's current timetable,](http://www.delta.com/content/dam/delta-www/pdfs/flight_schedules.pdf) Delta's early-evening flight from YYZ to JFK is currently operated by Endeavor Air, under the number 4126.<sup>1</sup>  It is scheduled to depart YYZ at 6:15 PM, and arrive at 8:11 PM.

According to the [FlightAware history for this flight](http://flightaware.com/live/flight/DAL4126/history), here are the arrival times that have been recorded for this flight over the past two weeks:

- Arrived early or on time on eight days;  early by 9, 11, 0, 30, 30, 2, 5, and 21 minutes
- Arrived late on four days;  delays of 21, 98, 91, and 57 minutes
- Cancelled on two days

So if you had picked a random day to make this flight over the last two weeks, you would have missed your flight to Edinburgh five times out of fourteen, and would have been dashing through JFK on one other occasion.  Given this performance, I would not personally want to book this connection;  but perhaps you like to live life on the edge.

---

<sup>1</sup> The flight will switch to Flight #6304 as of March 8;  it will also switch operators, from Endeavor Air (currently) to GoJet.

Answer (score 4):

You are doing preclearance at YYZ and then connect at JFK to an international flight. This makes it a domestic-to-international connection. For that, the relevant Minimum Connection Time is

> DL-DL DI   .45 CANADA - ALL

in general

> DL-DL DI   .50 TRM 2  - 4

So the computer will happily say, hey, 51 minutes, I can sell you this ticket and you can buy it, no problems but I would definitely plan for arriving a day later...

Comment: DL6304 arrived 58 minutes late yesterday...

Comment: If the MCT is what it says on the tin then a tenth of that is enough to be late from your connection.